# Inconsistent treatment of quotes in JSON payload

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

Why is it possible to send in a WCF DataService the following JSON string:

```
{ SomeElement: 'val1', SomeOtherElement: 'val2' }
```

whilest you have to send in an normal WCF Service like

```
[OperationContract,
 WebInvoke (Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public string SomeMehtod(string SomeElement, string SomeOtherElement)
```

the following JSON string

```
{ "SomeElement": "val1", "SomeOtherElement": "val2" }
```

This inconsistency is not clear to me. Why do I have to use double quotes in the normal web serive whilest I can omit the quotes for the element name in WCF data services?

Maybe somone knows an answer to this....

Comment: The JSON standard (http://www.json.org/) requires that the element name be quoted, and requires double quotes for all strings. So your first example is valid JavaScript, but not valid JSON. But that doesn't really explain the inconsistency.

Comment: Yes that's correct and WCF data service seems also accept double quotes. It seems like WCF is here more tolerant than normal WCF. Strange thing though, because WCF data services where introduced after WCF... I'm just curious...

Comment: What verb are you using to call your WCF Data Service (GET, POST, PUT, etc.)?  Is it also a POST?  And is it a custom service method?

Comment: Basically it doesn't matter if it's a POST or a PUT, in this case it was a POST but PUT works also. It's not a custom service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very familiar with the internal plumbing behind WCF's JSON parsing infrastructure, and essentially, the plumbing that takes care of the second situation is really designed to support "strict" standards-complaint JSON.

It's just a coincidence that the first situation works with non-compliant JSON. Don't read into it. It was not a conscious design decision. Hope this clears up confusion!

For more details, you can just explore DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter, DataContractJsonSerializerOperationBehavior, and DataContractJsonSerializer using Reflector.